# Ansible modules ec2_vpc and ec2_vpc_net: what's the difference?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

[ec2_vpc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_module.html) is older than [ec2_vpc_net](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_net_module.html), and they have the same description, but the first is not deprecated. They take somewhat different options, but they seem to talk about the same information or settings on a VPC. Do they have different scopes? Is one preferred over the other? Is it situational?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/1133) that added ec2_vpc_net. It says that the old ec2_vpc module was too monolithic, so new modules were added to set up different pieces of a VPC independently: ec2_vpc_net, ec2_vpc_subnet, ec2_vpc_route_table, etc.

ec2_vpc is planned to be deprecated, but that hasn't happened yet (v2.0 of Ansible).